# JSON to object array format

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ruby

I want to display like convert JSON data to array objects how can solve this problem using jquery or js? 
JSON data :

```
[{
  "new": 122,
  "old": 3389,
  "boarding": 1,
  "aws": 10,
  "azure": 12,
  "cli": 41
}];
```

To array object:

```
[
  ["new", 122],
  ["old", 3389],
  ["boarding", 1]
]
```

one more pattern I need it I have an array like this in Ruby

```
 [37, 
  3, 
  261, 
  1, 
  0, 
  1457]
```

to convert into add as key entry static

```
[
["new",37],
["old",3],
["boarding",1]
["aws",0]
["azure",1457]
]
```

Comment: Did you deliberately omit `"aws":10,"azure":12,"cli":41` from your desired output?

Comment: no just give example for look like this way ...

Comment: Will the input array always have exactly one item (the object)? If not, what would the output look like with for several objects?

Answer (score 4):

Firstly note that you do not need jQuery at all for this. jQuery is primarily a tool for amending the DOM. To work with data structures like this native JS is all you need.

To achieve what you require, you can use `Object.keys()` to get the keys of the 0th object in your original array, then you can loop over them using `map()` to build a new 2 dimensional array from that data:

```js
var originalArr = [{
  "new": 122,
  "old": 3389,
  "boarding": 1,
  "aws": 10,
  "azure": 12,
  "cli": 41
}];

var newArr = Object.keys(originalArr[0]).map(function(key) {
  return [key, originalArr[0][key]];
});

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Its simple enough. Just enter the array into Object.entries(). like this Object.entries(originalArr[0])

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. In an ideal world it's a great solution, the issue is it's completely unsupported in any version of IE

Answer (score 1):

A simple one-line alternative:

```
const data = [{
  "new": 122,
  "old": 3389,
  "boarding": 1,
  "aws": 10,
  "azure": 12,
  "cli": 41
}];

const result = Object.keys(data[0]).map(k => ([k, data[0][k]]));

console.log(result);
```